# win32_networkadapterconfiguration class does not return complete network adapter name if IP is disabled

Tags: vbscript

I have 2 network adapters say abc and abc #1. I use the following code to fetch the adapter names and IP addressed. If the ipv4 address on "abc #1" is enabled, everything works fine. But if I disable the ipv4 address on "abc #1", i get it's name as "abc" instead of "abc #1"

```
query= "SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WHERE MACAddress > ''"
Set objServ= GetObject( "winmgmts://./root/CIMV2" )
Set arrCol= objWMIService.ExecQuery( query, "WQL", 48 )
For Each item In arrCol
        If IsArray( item.IPAddress ) Then
             ip = item.IPAddress(0)
        End If
        adaptername = item.Description
Next
```

Comment: You cannot rely on `Caption` or `Description` to identify a network adapter because when releasing or renewing an IP the adapter order can move around and is not fixed. Instead use the `MACAddress` which uniquely identifies the network adapter.

Comment: I need to find the GUID of the adapter. Currently I use the description to iterate over a registry that has the GUID in it's path. Any idea direction on how I would use MACAddress to find the GUID? Or is there any way to directly get the GUID of the adapter?

Comment: If you type this command on your cmd console did you get the GUID or Not ? `netsh wlan show interfaces`

Comment: You should be able to get the guid from [`Win32_NetworkAdapter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-networkadapter) by searching via the `MACAddress`.